# Use hostPort on nginx ingress controller is insecure?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm using nginx-ingress controller (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller) and I would like to know if expose ingress using hostPort is insecure. I am currently using nodePort with a balancer layer 3 / 4 on the front.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not insecure on it's own it's just REALLY not recommended, it all depend on the security of the deployment that is exposed , and the security of your host.

Also , exposing hostPort is not recommended outside of a test stage , because , you can deploy only on pod per host/node (as only one port is available).

If you achieve what you wanted to do using nodeport , stick to it , as it's the best choice if you are using a Loadbalancer in front of your cluster

Comment: Thank you @Popopame. But I would like to remove load balancer in front of my cluster. Because if a need to scale my cluster, I need to reconfigure my load balancer. I use bare metal servers.

Comment: For your LoadBalancer , you could configure it to watch over a range of IP , the loadbalancer can then , only send request to the IP that are responding in the given IP range. So if a new node is added , the LoadBalancer will discover it on it's own , I know that HAproxy have a fonctionallity like so. If you really want to get rid of your loadbalancer , maybe look a MetalLB , wich is a Loadbalancer that can run on Kubernetes. Also this link can help you: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/

Comment: Ok. But whats the problem to have only one ingress controller pod per host/node? My ideia is to use only one node in my cluster to put ingress controller that with a public ip. The external clients send request to that external IP.  That is a bad idea?

Comment: For a production context , it is a very bad idea , because all of your infrastructure network depend on one node. If the node with the ingress controller dies (or loose connection or watherver) , all your cluster loose connection to the outside world , plus it is a big hole in your security , if you expose your nginx  to the host network , the nginx pod have acces to all the system daemon , if the NGINX in corrupted : your system is exposed. If this is for a Homelab or test context , why not , but why do something that will never be made in a production context ?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It clarified many things to me.

Comment: No Probleme , don't forget to mark this question as closed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the application requirements.  For very small, one node clusters, it seems like `hostPort` is exactly what you want.  `ingress-nginx` suggests you configure it to use `DaemonSet` instead of `Deployment` to make sure "there can be only one" per node.